# Why does Java throw NullPointerException using HashMap with Dagger?

Tags: java, dagger

First I create Dagger Component and Module.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {UploadModule.class})
public interface UploadComponent {
    void inject(UploadS3ToMap requestHandler);
}
```

Module:

```
private Map<String, String> uploadMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Singleton
@Provides
Map<String, String> getUploadMap() {
    return uploadMap;
}
```

And than trying to use it in my Class:

```
@Inject
Map<String,String> getUploadMap;

getUploadMap.put("test", "testIssue");
return getUploadMap.toString();
```

And I have an Exception: `nulljava.lang.NullPointerException`

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Someone has marked a question to be closed. If this issue is clear for you, what prevent you to write a short answer for author and community?

Comment: Exceptions are thrown, not returned.

Comment: Obviously your map is not being injected. You should provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem is you need more help.

Comment: @Slaw Thank your for your support. I am working on it now.